# How to support multiple transport types with MKDirectionsRequest

Tags: ios, mapkit

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
request.source = source;
request.destination = destination;
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny;

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateETAWithCompletionHandler:^(MKETAResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    ...
}];
```

First of all, `response.transportType` here is `MKDirectionsTransportTypeWalking`. Why does it choose that?

Second, what I really want is travel time for all 3 transport types, Transit, Walking, and Automobile. What is the best way to get all three? It seems wasteful to create 3 MKDirectionsRequest objects and run this code 3 times with different transport types. Surely Apple anticipated that we would need a way to get all 3 at once right?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question -

If you go to Maps Settings in Settings preferred transport type might have set to walking thats why you are getting walking directions. I believe it will override if walking time is more than some threshold.

For second try passing multiple options with '|'  eg. MKDirectionsTransportTypeWalking | MKDirectionsTransportTypeDriving. Not sure if it will work or not but worth trying. One more thing to note MKDirectionsTransportTypeTransit is only supported for ETA and does not return directions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think there's an answer to my problem (aside from creating 3 different MKDirectionRequests and MKDirections). +1 for the suggestions though.